# How to remove Python "1 of 1 completed"

Tags: python, laravel

I am using a Python Script on my Laravel Project.

I am able to run the Python Script properly with no issues, but the output of "shell_exec" in my Laravel project also returns `[*********************100%***********************] 1 of 1 completed` along with the results I want.

How do I remove the `[*********************100%***********************] 1 of 1 completed` part? The result is a string.

How I am using **shell_exec**: `$result = shell_exec("python " . public_path() . "\storage\python\python.py 2>&1");`

Not so sure if this is a PHP or Python issue.

Comment: strstr works, but it would be better if I didn't have to do this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: Have you checked where this output comes from?

Answer (score 0):

`   use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

```
$command ="python ".public_path() . "/storage/python/python.py";

$proc = Process::fromShellCommandline($command, null, [])->mustRun()->
getOutput();
//getErrorOutput();
echo $proc;`
```

(and don't forget python.py to make executable.)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - how does this help to remove a linke from the output?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend running it as a Symfony Process (Included in laravel)

```
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

    $command = "python " . public_path() . "\storage\python\python.py";
    Process::fromShellCommandline($command, null, [])->mustRun();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - how does this help to remove a linke from the output?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it. Don't rely on external links only, better **explain** why this approach could solve the problem

Comment: I appreciate your emphasis on high quality responses here, but I am trying to help solve this person's problem, and my time is valuable. I will not write out help docs.